# Why do changing className on body have same performance impact as changing className on body?

Tags: performance-testing, repaint, reflow, web-performance

I recently learn about web optimization. There are some resources that mentioned,

> changing the class of a root node is more costly than a leaf node.

So I tried to proof that by recording the performance of ([Google](https://www.google.com/)) and change className of a body node and a leaf node (#hplogo).

But here what I found:
(Sorry I can't post any image, don't have enough reputation to do that here)

- body:
  [body](https://i.postimg.cc/SSbnqJDn/body-1.png)
- #hplogo:
  [leaf-node](https://i.postimg.cc/HWsss55k/leaf-1.png)

So is it true that changing the class of a root node is more costly than a leaf node?

Comment: Google's home page is probably not the best example, it only has a few hundred nodes. Try on a page with several thousands nodes. It is supposed to be more costly because the algorithm needs to crawl every node on the page and check for change.

Comment: It has 354 nodes. I tried it again with firefox which has 66 nodes. And the recalculate style time of changing the class of a root node is higher than the leaf one.

Is google still a special case?

Comment: I didn't mean "try with another browser", but "try with another page". Choose a large page with more than 8000 nodes. Like some e-commerce websites or newspaper homepages...